# Append symbol to each line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a sort of code-box on my site where I want a symbol appearing first on each line. Example:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install john
```

It's that **$** sign that appears first that I want on each and every line. I managed to get it to at least the first line on each block with this short css line:

```
pre code.terminal:before {
    content: '$ ';
}
```

And this is the HTML

```
<pre><code class="language-terminal">cp /mnt/etc/passwd ~/Desktop/crack
cp /mnt/etc/shadow ~/Desktop/crack</code></pre>
```

I think I'll need to use JS to for each line append the **$** sign but I'm not sure how, any suggestions?

Comment: CSS can't add a character before each line. Possible solution could be to add a character using `:before` before the first line, the other dollars add by JS replacing - `\n` for `\n$ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great way to deal with this client side is to put it in a special `<script>` tag and tokenize it during runtime. Then CSS styles can be applied to each token.

Here the only token is a line:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("script[type=bash]").forEach(ele => {
  var pre = document.createElement("pre"),
      code = document.createElement("code"),
      lines = ele.textContent.trim().split("\n").map(l => l.trim());
      
  lines.forEach(l => {
    var line = document.createElement("span");
    line.classList.add("line");
    line.textContent = l;
    code.appendChild(line);
  });
  
  pre.appendChild(code);
  pre.classList.add("bash");
  ele.parentNode.replaceChild(pre, ele);
});
```

```css
.bash .line{
  display: block;
}

.bash .line::before{
  content: "$ ";
}
```

```html
<script type="bash">
cp /mnt/etc/passwd ~/Desktop/crack
cp /mnt/etc/shadow ~/Desktop/crack
</script>
```

Comment: I have to use the current way of doing it with <pre> tags and <code> inside it. Otherwise this would've been a good way I guess

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by you have to use the current way. The code simply generates `<pre><code></code></pre>` for you from a data source.

Comment: @Condolent The required html structure is present - you can verify this by inspecting the elements in question generated by the embedded code snippet.

Comment: Since I'm using prismjs for syntax highlighting, I had to add this to your code in order for it to work properly with highlighting: `code.classList.add('language-terminal');`. However, it won't actually do a linebreak now :/

Comment: @Condolent If you are using Prism.js, you should just use their command line prefixes... http://prismjs.com/plugins/command-line/

Comment: I'm actually minorly retarded, I really don't know how I've missed this... Well well.. Good to know now atleast if I would make a custom codeblock in the future! thanks

Comment: @Condolent FYI, next time when you are asking a question, try to include all the information about the thing that you are working on. It would be really helpful for example in this case to know that you are using Prism.js

Answer (score 1):

As I've commented under question, add dollar signs after each new line in pre/code.

Note that I've updated CSS selector, you used bad classname.

https://jsfiddle.net/ruppf1n6/

```
<style>
pre code.language-terminal:before {
    content: '$ ';
}
</style>

<pre><code class="language-terminal">cp /mnt/etc/passwd ~/Desktop/crack
cp /mnt/etc/shadow ~/Desktop/crack</code></pre>

<script>
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('code')[0];

el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace("\n", "\n$ ");
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, sadly. I guess I'm doing something wrong